# how to know the changed name in table by date_key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics, identifier

i have a table with 3 value

```
Date_key    | user_name  | user_id
2022-07-12  | milkcotton | 1
2022-09-12  | cereal     | 2
2022-06-12  | musicbox1  | 3
2022-12-31  | harrybel1  | 1
2022-12-25  | milkcotton1| 4
2023-01-01  | cereal     | 2
```

i want to know the user who changed the user_name in 1 semester (01 july 2022 - 31 december 2022). Can i do this?
my expected value is:

```
previous_name| new_name  | user_id
milkcotton  | harrybel1 | 1
```

Thank you!

know the changed of the user_name from 1 table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This is done in Postgres SQL. This should be similar in most of the SQL engines. Date functions could slightly different in other SQL engines.

Try this:

```
with BaseTbl as(
 select *,
  cast(to_char(Date_key, 'YYYYMM') as int) as year_month,
  cast(to_char(Date_key, 'MM') as int) as month,
  row_number() over(partition by user_id order by date_key desc) as rnk
 from Table1
   ),
   LatestTwoChanges as(
  select * 
  from BaseTbl
  where user_id in (select user_id from BaseTbl where rnk=2 ) 
  and rnk <=2
   )
  select 
  t2.user_name as previous_name,
  t1.user_name as new_name,
  t1.user_id
  from LatestTwoChanges t1
  join LatestTwoChanges t2
  on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
  where t1.rnk=1
  and t2.rnk=2
  and t1.year_month-t2.year_month <6
  and t1.user_name <> t2.user_name
  and (t1.month + t2.month <= 12 or  t1.month + t2.month >=14 )
  -- this is to check whether the date falling in the same semester.
```

SQL fiddle demo **[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4333/26)**

Here, the table t1 contains the latest changes and table t2 contains the previous changes for a user_id.
The last filter condition

```
and (t1.month + t2.month <= 12 or  t1.month + t2.month >=14 )
```

is to make sure that the two dates are falling in the same semester or not . which means the two months should be either between 1 and 6 or 7 and 12